# pthread_join causes segmentation error (simple program)

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, pthreads, pthread-join

I am just trying to work with multi-threaded programs, but I am having problems with the pthread_join function. The code below is just a simple program I am using to show pthread_join crashing. The output from this code will be:

```
before create

child thread

after create

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What causes pthread_join to give a segmentation fault?

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void * dostuff() {
    printf("child thread\n");
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t p1;

    printf("before create\n");
    pthread_create(&p1, NULL, dostuff(), NULL);
    printf("after create\n");

    pthread_join(p1, NULL);
    printf("joined\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you've enabled and listened to all your compiler warnings? This looks like a lot of avoidable mistakes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because in your call to `pthread_create` you actually *call* the function, and as it returns `NULL` `pthread_create` will fail. This will not properly initialize `p1` and so will (probably) cause undefined behavior in the `pthread_join` call.

To fix this pass the function pointer to the `pthread_create` call, do not call it:

```
pthread_create(&p1, NULL, dostuff, NULL);
/* No parantehsis --------^^^^^^^ */
```

This should also teach you to check the return values of function calls, as `pthread_create` will return non-zero on failure.

Answer (score 5):

You need to fix your function type and the way you call `pthread_create`:

```
void * dostuff(void *) { /* ... */ }
//             ^^^^^^
```

```
pthread_create(&p1, NULL, dostuff, NULL);
//                        ^^^^^^^
```